# How can I throw exception if user does not enter a binary value

Tags: java, exception, binary, try-catch, throw

I want to take input as a binary value from user. If he does not enter binary (for example: 3214), then i want to give WrongFormatException. But I could not manage try-throw-catch things. Here is my controller class.

**I worked a little and changed it to it. Is there any funny part that i should change ?** Its working btw. thanks for help

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Controller {

private View theView;
private Model theModel;

public Controller( View theView, Model theModel ){

    this.theView = theView;
    this.theModel = theModel;

    theView.addListener( new MyActionListener());   
}

public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        int inputBinary = theView.getInputBinary();

        try {
            if ( checkFormat(inputBinary) )
            {
                int outputDecimal = theModel.convertToDecimal(Integer.toString(inputBinary));
                theView.setOutputDecimal(outputDecimal);
            }                   
            else
            {
                throw new WrongFormatException( "Wrong format");
            }

        } catch ( WrongFormatException e ) {

            theView.setOutputDecimal(0);
            theView.displayErrorMessage( "Wrong Format");
        }

    }
}

public boolean checkFormat ( int input )
{
    // check if it is not in true format
    String stringInput = Integer.toString(input);           
    for ( int i = 0; i < stringInput.length(); i++ )
    {
        if ( stringInput.charAt(i) == '0' || stringInput.charAt(i) == '1' )
        {

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// my own exception class
public class WrongFormatException extends Exception
{

    // CONSTRUCTOR

    public WrongFormatException( String message )
    {
        super( message );
    }

}   
}
```

first Codes here, but ignore this part.

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Controller {

private View theView;
private Model theModel;

public Controller( View theView, Model theModel ){

    this.theView = theView;
    this.theModel = theModel;

    theView.addListener( new MyActionListener());   
}

public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        // we got the input
        int inputBinary = theView.getInputBinary();

        // create an exception
        WrongFormatException problem = new WrongFormatException( "Input value is not binary");

        // base value, we assme the input is in true format
        boolean isTrueFormat = true;

        // check if it is not in true format
        String stringBinary = Integer.toString(inputBinary);            
        for ( int i = 0; i < stringBinary.length(); i++ )
        {
            if ( stringBinary.charAt(i) == '0' || stringBinary.charAt(i) == '1' )
            {

            }
            else
            {
                isTrueFormat = false;
                i = stringBinary.length();
            }
        }

        // we do the convertion work here
        int outputDecimal = theModel.convertToDecimal(Integer.toString(inputBinary));

        // and we set output textfield
        theView.setOutputDecimal(outputDecimal);


    }
}

// my own exception class
public class WrongFormatException extends Exception
{

    // CONSTRUCTOR

    public WrongFormatException( String message )
    {
        super( message );
    }

}   
}
```

Comment: Side note: In Java, the stack information for an exception is stored when it is constructed, not when it is thrown (as in .NET). So, consider calling `new WrongFormatException` closer to the point where the exception is thrown. In most cases, exception code looks like: `throw new `….

Comment: What is the point in throwing a `WrongFormatException` if you immediately catch it (in `MyActionListener#actionPerformed`)?

Comment: yeah, i questioned this too. but i just wanted to learn throwing exception :D

Answer (score 2):

You can throw WrongFormatException from the else block without declaring a throws clause if you extend java.lang.RuntimeException instead of java.lang.Exception

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) to validate that the input is in binary. `parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException` exception if the input is not in the correct format, making it quite easy to parse and check if valid.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a binary value: ");
    String input = in.nextLine();

    int value = 0;
    try {
        value = Integer.parseInt(input, 2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {
        throw new WrongFormatException("Input value is not binary");// incorrect format
    }

    System.out.println("You entered \"" + value + "\" in base 10");
}
```

One thing to watch for, the docs on `parseInt` say:

> ... except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value ...

So you may need to check for that...

**Edit:** saw from comments that I missed the point. Your new code is perfectly fine.

Comment: woow. that was brilliant. however, i want to learn about throwing exceptions for my exam :( and i just choosed binary example

Comment: In that case, this may help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Answer (score 1):

The user enters a String, so test it as a string simply like this:

```
if (!input.matches("[01]+"))
    // it's not a binary, so throw exception etc
```

Comment: I got rid of checkFormat method. Thanks